# swapping src to lazy

Tags: javascript, image, lazy-loading, setattribute

Not happy with existing lazy loading plugins (they are so complex that I can't even understand the codes in them), I thought I can create a simple, easy to understand script that lazy loads images.

My idea was simple.  Start out with a following (deformed) img tag.

```
<img lazy="http://lorempixel.com/400/200"/>
```

Using javascript, swap out the word "lazy" with "src" when the page is being scrolled up or down.

```
function hackyaFunction_lazy() {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('img[lazy]'), function(img) {
    img.setAttribute('src', img.getAttribute('lazy'));

    img.onload = function() {

      var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('[lazy]');
      for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        var o = imgs[i],
          lazy = o.getAttribute('lazy');
        if (o.y <= (window.screen.height + window.scrollY + 50) && o.y >= (window.scrollY - 50)) {
          o.setAttribute('src', lazy);
          o.removeAttribute('lazy');
        }
      }
    }
    window.onload = window.onscroll = hackyaFunction_lazy;

  });
}
```

I know enough of javascript to hack together bits & pieces to make something that works. And the above code kinda works.

On my console, I see that the word "lazy" has been successfully replaced with "src" for images that are in viewport.

However, images that are outside of the viewport, this is what I see.

```
<img lazy="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/Dummy-Text" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/Dummy-Text">
```

So I have half working code & this is the best that I can do.

I should have just used any one of the plugins that are available out there; just wanted to see if I can create something simple & easy.

Now that I am so close to making this thing work, I am reluctant to give it up.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I wanted to put together the whole thing (html & js) on jsfiddle but images fail to show on jsfiddle.  Don't know why.

The code works (as described) on local environment.

Comment: I don't understand what the `img.onload` function is for given that the first line of the `forEach()` is already changing the current `img[lazy]` image to set its `src`, and after all iterations of the `forEach()` all will have been changed. Also, why is `window.onload = window.onscroll = hackyaFunction_lazy;` *inside* the function? (Also, why are you using `setAttribute()` when you can just say `img.src = `?)

Comment: if I don't wait for the image to load first, the js (the part that changes lazy to src on scroll) fires prematurely, breaking the script.

I wouldn't know how I can do" img.src =" & later remove that attribute.  Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: If the idea is to set the src once an image is in view,  I *think* what you need is to get rid of the `.forEach` and the `img.onload` and just keep the inner `for` loop and the `var imgs = ` line before it. Then assign `window.onload = window.onscroll = hackyaFunction_lazy;` *outside* the function. That way, each time the function runs, it will change the `src` *only* for the images currently in view (and only if not previously loaded). The only attribute you remove is the `'lazy'` one, so there's no reason you can't set `img.src = ` and still use `o.removeAttribute('lazy')`.

Comment: I really don't get how I can set the image attribute before defining it first.

If I get rid of [].forEach... "img" becomes meaningless.  So the code would break from the very first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first line within the `.forEach()` changes the `src` of the current image without removing `lazy` and without testing whether it is in view or not, so after the `.forEach()` has run that line for every image they will *all* have been updated. That's why when you inspect the elements with the dev tools many of the images have both a `src` and `lazy` attribute.

If the idea is to only set the `src` once the image scrolls into view, and for any images that are already in view on page load, you can do it by keeping just the inner `for` loop of your function:

```
function hackyaFunction_lazy() {
  var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('[lazy]');
  for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    var o = imgs[i];
    if (o.y <= (window.screen.height + window.scrollY + 50) && o.y >= (window.scrollY - 50)) {
      o.src = o.getAttribute('lazy');
      o.removeAttribute('lazy');
    }
  }
}

window.onload = window.onscroll = hackyaFunction_lazy;
```

This works because on each scroll it first selects whatever elements still have the `lazy` attribute, then for those elements it tests whether they're in view and if so it sets their `src` and removes the `lazy`. Elements that have not yet been scrolled into view are not updated.

See it working here: https://jsfiddle.net/vb779g7v/2/

Edit/P. S. Note that your `if` test checking if the element is in view isn't right, because `screen.height` gives, as the name suggests, the height of the whole *screen*, not the height of the client area within the browser. But that's not really central to your question, so I'll leave fixing that as an exercise for the reader...

Comment: Sorry I can't upvote your answer as I lack the reputation; had lost my login credential & I am using Google login which doesn't show my past reputation points.

I understand your code & I really appreciate your answer.  Thank You!!

I am just frustrated/angry that I couldn't write the code myself.  I mean, I completely understand how/why your code works.  I just can't understand why I couldn't write it like this myself. sigh....